# Does `#[test]` imply `#[cfg(test)]`?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, attributes, visibility

Conventionally, unit tests in Rust are given a separate module, which is conditionally compiled with `#[cfg(test)]`:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test1() { ... }

    #[test]
    fn test2() { ... }
}
```

However, I've been using a style where tests are more inline:

```
pub fn func1() {...}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn test_func1() {...}

pub fn func2() {...}

#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn test_func2() {...}
```

My question is, does `#[test]` imply `#[cfg(test)]`? That is, if I tag my test functions with `#[test]` but not `#[cfg(test)]`, will they still be correctly absent in non-test builds?

Comment: It [does seem so](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=343d6ccd35093317ec8db96ca36b2205).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My question is, does `#[test]` imply `#[cfg(test)]`? That is, if I tag my test functions with `#[test]` but not `#[cfg(test)]`, will they still be correctly absent in non-test builds?

Yes. If you are not using a separate module for tests then you don't need to use `#[cfg(test)]`. Functions marked with `#[test]` are already excluded from non-test builds. This can be verified very easily:

```
#[test]
fn test() {}

fn main() {
    test(); // error[E0425]: cannot find function `test` in this scope
}
```

Comment: I find that, in practice, I create little helper functions and types in order to thoroughly  test my code. Those benefit from the conditionally-compiled nested `test` module.

Comment: @Shepmaster Also it's good for mocking types and functions from the std library, for example `Instant`, which is hard to work with in tests otherwise.

Comment: I don't know if that's useful information to anyone, but another way to [test this is with `compile_error!`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3aa4f181b45b9ea908548efbcbd8740b).

Comment: @Shepmaster for that kind of stuff I use a test module (or, more commonly, a whole separate `tests` directory), but for quick inline stuff where a doctest isn't warrented I've found I really like the item-test-item-test pattern.