# Check if Rust is running a test build

Tags: rust

I can use `cfg!(debug_assertions)` to check if the Rust project is running in development mode, but I'd like to know how to check if a test is being run. Is there a similar flag for tests I can use in an `if` statement?

The reason is to prevent database writes while running integration tests.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55995061/1233251

Comment: Why don't you have a trait for the database operations that has 2 implementations: a mock, and the production operations?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I do, and that's why I'd like to detect which one to use by detecting if it's running in a test. Also I don't mock because it would make it less of an integration test.

Comment: @E_net4 can that be used in an `if` statement? I.e. `cfg!(test)`. I've not tried it

Answer (score 18):

You can use `cfg!(test)`:

```
if cfg!(test) {
    // do test stuff
} else {
    // do non-test stuff
}
```

However, this can lead to fragile code. For example, you might accidentally not execute some code in production, even though the tests all pass. It is often more robust to switch code at the item level, which would result in a compile error if you get it wrong:

```
#[cfg(test)]
impl Write for DB {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        // test stuff
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        // test stuff
    }
}

#[cfg(not(test))]
impl Write for DB {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        // actually write
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        // actually flush
    }
}
```

If you forget to implement the `not(test)` version, you will get a compilation error.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Did you test this? I'd be curious to know if it works for you

Comment: Yes, it works for me,

Comment: Are you running it with `cargo test` and is this via the unit test convention or integration test convention?

Comment: Try in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38b1ecd1cde65003406dafd600bdb400

Comment: Hm, I don't think this flag is getting set using the [integration testing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/integration_testing.html) convention. The example uses private functions, so it can't be testing externally as a `lib`.

Comment: It seems `cfg!(test)` doesn't work with integration tests

Comment: This chapter explains that it won't work for integration tests: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html

Comment: You could use the `CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>` env var to check if you're running in an integration test. For unit tests, though, `cfg!(test)` is a great solution!

Comment: Can't edit my comment, but noting the above only works for integration tests for binaries. Don't know of a way to figure out if you're in an integration test for a library.

Comment: I'm relying on scripts to run my integration tests, so what I've been doing is passing an environment variable and I detect whether that env variable is set. Wish there would be a more universal method though